# Best Practices for Installing Metal Vent Caps on Cast Iron Vent Stacks - Preventing Galvanic Corrosion

Tags: plumbing, roof, vent, cast-iron

I'm in the process of replacing vent caps on my roof's sewer cast iron vent stacks. I have a few concerns about galvanic corrosion and proper installation:

1. Galvanic Corrosion Concerns: I'm considering using metal vent caps. Is there a risk of galvanic corrosion when these caps come into contact with the cast iron stacks? If so, how can I mitigate this risk?
2. Use of Separators: Would using a rubber separator or sealant material be effective in preventing metal-on-metal contact and thus galvanic corrosion? Are there specific products recommended for this purpose?
3. Existing Peel and Stick Material: One of the vent stacks is currently wrapped with peel and stick roofing material. Would placing a metal cap on this, using the peel and stick material as a barrier, be sufficient to prevent corrosion?
4. Installation Tips: If you have any tips or best practices for installing these vent caps, especially in terms of ensuring a secure and weatherproof fit, please share.

I have pictures of the current vent stacks and would be happy to provide them for more context.

[image: 4inch Sewer Vent Stack]
[image: 4inch Sewer Vent Stack2]
[image: 3inch Sewer Vent Stack]
[image: 3inch Sewer Vent Stack2 - Snug Fit]
[image: 3inch Water Heater Vent Stack]

Comment: Pictures always help. Is there some driving reason for capping your vent stacks? In my region they are typically left wide open. Also, I don't believe galvanic action is a concern with vent pipes, because there is no electrolyte (like water, in a water line) present, so any electron movement (i.e., corrosion) would be very slight and very slow...

Comment: What kind of metal would you be using? Are you worried about the cap itself corroding? Why are you capping plumbing vents? Critters?

Comment: Simply to keep critters out where they shouldn't be. It was surprising to me that it was open. Why is this done and why isn't critter entry a concern? 
The only concern regarding corrosion would be humidity and precipitation. 

The Vent Stacks are cast iron sewer vents. I have galvanized aluminum and other vent caps available to me from the big box stores. I'll post pics.

Comment: Added photos for those interested.  I have a lot of Oak trees and a lot squirrels.